# Visual Basic - Button on website doesnt have an ID

Tags: forms, basic

I'm trying to build a application which logs you into instagram. I've got it to input the username + password no problem

However, when i go to get the ID for the submit button their isnt one.. and i've been using .GetElementById. Is their anyway around this?

I'm pretty new to visual basic so please dumb it down to simpleton terms! 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: How are you trying to carry out the login on instagram itself? From the sound of it, you're trying to scrape the page and kick off the function associated with the button, which is a fairly bad option. You would be better using their API to handle the log in, and holding the session token. An alternative would be to get elements of a type, and check the text for the button, but this is going to be a bit more of a faff.

Comment: As an option, you could use Sikuli for this. If you can find a VB example binding for it, you can simply grab an image of the button, and let Sikuli find it on the page for you and trigger the click. http://www.sikuli.org/

Comment: I was planning on doing something like      WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("LOGIN").InvokeMember("click")
But that isnt working

Comment: That sikuli looks awesome, i'll have a look and report back. Thank you!

Comment: Ah, ok, you have your web browser component in the VB form, that makes more sense. Are you working on the HtmlElementCollection? If so, GetElementByName could be the way to go. Is this VB6 or .NET?

Comment: Yeah haha, sorry i should have said that before hand. VB.NET

Comment: Ok, this is looking quite complex. The button isn't actually a button, it's an input element with a load of redacts. It doesn't have a name, or an ID as such. To find the input element, try GetElementsByTagName("input"); to get the input elements, then check each one for a type attribute of 'submit'. If there was a GetElementByType, it would solve the issue, but I don't think there is such a method.

Comment: Darn, would it be possible to  SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}") through the Web browser component? i understand this is pretty bad practise but i need this to work :P

Comment: I'd be surprised if that worked, but it would be worth a shot if you're stuck for other options, but personally, I would use the VB.NET API for it, and handle the login that way. You pass login details, and request a token. Whether you can use that token within the browser component I'm not sure. What is it you're actually trying to achieve? It's often easier to re-engineer your solution than it is to keep hacking away at it. Have a read through this - http://www.codeguru.com/columns/vb/creating-a-basic-instagram-app-with-visual-basic.html . It might give you an alternative approach

Comment: For somereason this doesnt work, theirs no reason it shouldn't (?) while it is bad practise
     WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("username").InvokeMember("select")
            Application.DoEvents()
            WebBrowser1.Select()
            SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}"

Comment: SendKeys sends a keystroke to the form, but not necessarily to the browser. I would speculate that this doesn't work as the brower doesn't have focus. If you can set the focus on the browser rather than using select, Sendkeys *might* route the keystroke correctly, although I'm still not certain it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting elements by ID is not the only solution. You can always get them by it's names or you can find the element by yourself. Just look at the whole page's source code, search for something spesific that button carries and invoke it. Visual basic's library can be insufficient for situations like that.

Comment: I don't have a computer in front of me right now. Let me help you when I go home.

Answer (score 0):

```
  WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("username").InvokeMember("select")
            WebBrowser1.Document.ActiveElement.Focus()
            SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
```

This is the code that works! Change the "username" ID to the form you will be changing, then it focuses onto it and presses enter! Simulating the submit button.